# get TextInput height without using event

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've actually a TextInput like that :

```js
<TextInput
    onChange={(event) => {
    this.setState({
        text: event.nativeEvent.text,
        height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
    });
    }}
    editable={!this.state.load}
    style={{height: this.state.inputFocused == true || this.state.text.length > 0 || this.state.picture.uri != undefined ? Math.max(height / 11.8, this.state.height) : height / 2.5, width: width, backgroundColor: 'white', fontFamily: 'Aller', fontSize: width / 24, padding: width / 38, alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start', textAlignVertical: 'top',}} 
    multiline={true}
    value={this.state.text}
/>
```

I'm using this TextInput to add content but also to **edit**, so I initialize class that uses it with default value in TextInput and height And the height of the textInput does not automatically adjust as I would like.

So how can I do to get height occupied by the text in a textInput without using any event ?

Answer (score 1):

just do not give it a height style, so it will not get any height and match its content height